# Smarty menu generation

Tags: web, smarty

Somehow, I cannot get this piece of Smarty code to work as required:

```
{assign var='number_of_levels' value=2}
{if isset($menuparams.number_of_levels)}
  {assign var='number_of_levels' value=$menuparams.number_of_levels}
{/if}

{if $count > 0}
<div id="sbi_container" class="sbi_container">

    {foreach from=$nodelist item=node}
        {if $node->depth == 1}
            <div class="sbi_panel" data-bg="images/3.jpg">
                <a href="#" class="sbi_label">{$node->menutext}</a>
                <div class="sbi_content">
                    <ul>
        {/if}

        {if $node->depth > 1}
                        <li><a href="{$node->url}">{$node->menutext}</a></li>
        {/if}

        {if $node->depth == 1 && $node->depth < $node->prevdepth}
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        {/if}
    {/foreach}
    </div>
{/if}
```

Desired output looks like this:

```
                <div id="sbi_container" class="sbi_container">

                <div class="sbi_panel" data-bg="images/3.jpg">
                    <a href="#" class="sbi_label">Web / Smartphones</a>
                    <div class="sbi_content">
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="#">Subitem</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Subitem</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Subitem</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="sbi_panel" data-bg="images/4.jpg">
                    <a href="#" class="sbi_label">Brothers</a>
                    <div class="sbi_content">
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="#">Subitem</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Subitem</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Subitem</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="sbi_panel" data-bg="images/5.jpg">
                    <a href="#" class="sbi_label">Video / Scripts</a>
                    <div class="sbi_content">
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="#">Subitem</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Subitem</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Subitem</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>
```

Filling the content is not a problem, but I fail to recreate the hierarchical order with div / ul / li elements. The menu has two levels only.

Please help, I feel stupid not to be able to do that myself. Thanks a looot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, here is what I was looking for. The structure is somehow counter-intuitive, but it fits my needs perfectly:

```
{if $count > 0}
<div id="sbi_container" class="sbi_container">
    {foreach from=$nodelist item=node}
        {if $node->index <> 0}
            {if $node->depth == 1}
                {if $node->depth < $node->prevdepth}
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                {/if}
                <div class="sbi_panel" data-bg="images/3.jpg">
                    <a href="#" class="sbi_label">{$node->menutext}</a>
                    <div class="sbi_content">
                        <ul>
            {/if}

            {if $node->depth == 2}
                            <li><a href="{$node->url}">{$node->menutext}</a></li>
            {/if}
        {/if}
    {/foreach}
    </div>
{/if}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use a 2-dimensonal array in PHP:

```
$nodelist = array();
$nodelist['Web / Smartphones'] = array();
$nodelist['Web / Smartphones']['Subitem1'] = 'http://..';
$nodelist['Web / Smartphones']['Subitem2'] = 'http://..';
$nodelist['Web / Smartphones']['Subitem3'] = 'http://..';
$nodelist['Brothers'] = array();
$nodelist['Brothers']['Subitem1'] = 'http://..';
$nodelist['Brothers']['Subitem2'] = 'http://..';
$nodelist['Brothers']['Subitem3'] = 'http://..';
```

Using this, you could loop through these in Smarty with:

```
{foreach from=$nodelist item=nodes key=menutext}
  <div class="sbi_panel" data-bg="images/3.jpg">
    <a href="#" class="sbi_label">{$menutext}</a>
    <div class="sbi_content">
      <ul>
      {foreach from=$nodes item=url key=menutext2}
        <li><a href="{$url}">{$menutext2}</a></li>
      {/foreach}
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
{/foreach}
```

Comment: Thx for your help. But this is not what I am looking for as I dont wanna copy the data into an array. I know there is a better way to achieve what I want.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need something like this (works with Smarty3)

```
<ul>
{function name=mytree}
   {foreach $data as $entry}
     <li>{$entry.label}</li>
   {if is_array($entry.children)}
      <ul>{mytree data=$entry.children}</ul>
   {/if}
   {/foreach}
{/function}
{mytree data=$same_array}
</ul>
```

Result of:

```
<ul>
  <li>Option 1</li>
  <li>Option 2
    <ul>
      <li>Option 2-1</li>
      <li>Option 2-2
        <ul>
          <li>Option 2-2-1</li>
          <li>Option 2-2-2</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>Option 2-3</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>Option 3</li>
</ul>
```